# Вставить переменную в include

Tags: symfony, twig

Как можно указать переменную с названием страницы в include ?
У меня есть бд в которой хранятся пути к шаблонам. Что-то вроде мини конструктора блоков хочу. Чтобы я указывала у страницы список отдельных блоков и выводила их через include.  Но если делаю так, то ошибка *Unable to find template "page/blocks/{{el.block}}/template.html.twig"*

```html
{% for el in page %}
    {% include 'page/blocks/{{el.block}}/template.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

И как после этого передать переменную `{{ el.content }}` внутрь блока include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкатенация строк в твиге выполняется через `~` (тильда):

```
{% for el in page %}
    {% include 'page/blocks/' ~ el.block ~ '/template.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```